Error with docker
I'm trying to run a pip install command in kubuntu 24.04 and i need python3.11
As stated in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1530570/2029166 installed docker.io and when trying to run it i get this error:
docker run -it --rm python:3.11
docker: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.

Did i do something wrong? How can i fix it?
